# Cannot update request parameters in custom Search Component

Tags: solr, lucene

I have written Solr Custom Search Component as described [here](http://rockthecode.io/blog/plug-in-to-solr-5-creating-a-custom-search-component/)

My goal is to update the query parameters, specifically to remove Unicode Quotes as early as possible in the pipeline.

However, after intercepting the request and editing the parameters, the request does not seem to update.

```
public void updateSolrRequest(SolrQueryRequest req) {
  SolrParams params = req.getParams();
  System.out.println( "params = " +  req.getParamString());
  String newQuery = params.get(CommonParams.Q);
  newQuery = newQuery.toString().replaceAll("[A]","XXX");
  ModifiableSolrParams newParams = new ModifiableSolrParams(params);
  newParams.remove(CommonParams.Q);
  newParams.add(CommonParams.Q, newQuery);

  // all good to here, the next line should 
  // overwrite the old params with the new ones
  // but it does not
  req.setParams(newParams);
  System.out.println("newQuery = " + newQuery);
  System.out.println("newParams = " + newParams.get(CommonParams.Q));
  System.out.println("updated req = " + req.getParamString());
}
```

Output

```
params = q=“A+Game+of+Thrones“&defType=dismax&q.alt=thrones&fq=Game&_=1548262845155
newQuery = “XXX Game of Thrones“
newParams = “XXX Game of Thrones“
updated req = q=“A+Game+of+Thrones“&defType=dismax&q.alt=thrones&fq=Game&_=1548262845155
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, that

```
public String getParamString() {
    return origParams.toString();
}
```

is actually returning original params, which aren't affected by `setParams` called

```
  /** Change the parameters for this request.  This does not affect
   *  the original parameters returned by getOriginalParams()
   */
  void setParams(SolrParams params);
```

You should use `org.apache.solr.request.SolrQueryRequest#getParams` to check your updated parameters.

Comment: Thanks @Mysterion. That explains why it worked but my tests failed.